# change a cell that was just entered based on multiplying with an adjacent field

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that I need to have change when the data is entered.  Tough to explain but this is the best way I can describe my situation:

> A     b    
>   1 .5    10   
>   2 .5    5    
>   3
>   The end user will be entering 10 in b1 and I want it to change to 5 as they enter it. I can not alter the columns as this is set form.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Sorry I can not figure out the formatting...

Answer (score 0):

You could put some some like this in the Worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Address = Range("B1").Address Then

    If Range("B1") = 10 Then

        Range("B1").Value =  5

    Else

        Range("B1").Value = 5

    End If

End If


End Sub
```